# A problem on symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices

> Let $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb R)$ be a symmetric real matrix. Prove that there exists a diagonal matrix $D \in  \operatorname{Mat}_n (\mathbb R)$ whose entries are chosen from $\{1,-1\}$ satisfying $$\det(A+D)\neq 0$$

---

It appears in a problem set of linear algebra...

I have thought about diagonalizing $A$ and calculating the determinant, but a congruent of $D$ is hard to handle. So I want to reduce the problem to the special case: $D$ is of the form $\operatorname{diag}(-I_s,I_{n-s})$ ($0\leq s \leq n )$. But I could not achieve it. It seems hard to commute diagonal entries of $D$... Could you share some ideas? Thank you!

Comment: what are your thought on it? What have you tried?

Comment: The form of the question is badly stated. Since you want to ask about the existence of $D$, you should not earlier say "let $D$ be...", as that implies that a concrete $D$ is given (just like a concrete $A$ is given).

Comment: It would be nice to have some background in which context this question arises. If one knew in which situation one is interested in this whole bunch of $2^n$ determinants, and why it is interesting that at least one of them should not vanish, then it might be easier to find an argument for (or against) this claim,

Comment: @Exodd Sorry, I forgot to write my thoughts down. I have tried something, and I want to reduce the problem to: the first s diagonal entries of $D$ are 1 and the remnant are -1(for some s), since in this case it would be much easier for calculation. But I could not achieve it.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thank you for your remind, I have edited my question.

Comment: see props 2.1 and 2.2 on page 5 of https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/invers.pdf

Comment: It is not necessarily to assume that $A$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This result is valid for any matrix and not only for symmetric ones.

Let $B$ be the matrix occupying the last $n-1$ rows and $n-1$ columns of $A$.  By induction there is a diagonal matrix  $D$ such that $D_{ii}=\pm 1$ and $\det(B+D)\neq 0$.
Define $D'=diagonal(x,D_{11},\ldots, D_{n-1,n-1})$.

Note that  $\det(A+D')=(a_{11}+x)\det(B+D)+ c$ which is a degree 1 polynomial on $x$. So $1$ and $-1$ cannot be both zeros of this polynomial.

Comment: Nice answer +1. I would be nitpicking if I were to complain about an inductive proof that forgets to state which is its base case and why the claim holds for it. For the record $n=0$ will do fine, every $0\times 0$ matrix (there is just one) has nonzero (namely equal to $1$) determinant.